# Joining a CSV and a TopoJSON together while utilizing d3.queue()

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

I have found very little d3 documentation on working with a JSON file for mapping and joining a CSV file of metrics using a common key.

I would like to utilize `d3.queue()` if possible. Up to this point I've been using `d3.map().set` but I am finding that is used for single key, value pairs, and doesn't appear to be usable for > 1 values. If I am off here someone please correct me.

I was attempting to utilize a double `for` loop found in [this](http://bl.ocks.org/simzou/6459889) bl.ock. The creator here is using two JSON files and I've had little luck tailoring it to my needs. Link to his two JSON files are below, for what it's worth.

[tv.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/simzou/nielsen-dma/master/tv.json)

[neilsontopo.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/simzou/nielsen-dma/master/nielsentopo.json)

The join key (I speak SQL much better than JS) to be used is `counties.id` from the JSON and the `county_fips` value in the CSV.

Is it problematic that the `county_fips` in the CSV is flattened with the metrics tied to it? The double `for` loop in the example linked above uses the hierarchy of a JSON.

```
d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json")
    //.defer(d3.csv, "countymetrics_json.csv" , function(d) {metrics.set(d.county_fips, +d.actual_margin);})
    .defer(d3.csv, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MatthewSnellOKC/mapping/master/merge/countymetrics_json.csv", function(d) {metrics.set(d.county_fips, +d.actual_margin);})
    .await(ready);

function ready (error, us) {
    if (error) throw error;
    var counties = us.objects.counties.geometries;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have transitioned from using `d3.queue()` and `d3.map().set` and was able to join the CSV to JSON using a double `for` loop. See below for working code.

```
d3.json("https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json", function(error, us) {
    if (error) throw error;

    d3.csv("countymetrics_json.csv", function(error, csv) {
        var counties = us.objects.counties.geometries;

        csv.forEach(function(d, i) {
            counties.forEach(function(e, j) {
                if (d.county_fips == e.id) {
                    e.actual_margin = d.actual_margin;
                    e.state_code = d.state_code;
                    e.state_name = d.state_name;
                    e.county = d.county;
                    e.county_population = d.county_population;
                    e.business_population = d.business_population;
                    e.active_merchants = d.active_merchants;
                    e.actual_margin = d.actual_margin;
                }
            })
        })
    })
});
```